# Recognizing the 4-sphere and the Adjan--Rabin theorem

Tags: algorithms, at.algebraic-topology, tag-removed, differential-topology

The problem of recognizing the standard $S^n$ is the following:
Given some simplicial complex $M$ with rational vertices representing a closed manifold,
can one decide (in finite time) if $M$ is homeomorphic to $S^n$.

For $n=1$, this is obvious,
and for $n=2$,
one can solve it by computing $\chi(M)$.
A solution for $n=3$ is due to

J.H. Rubinstein. An algorithm to recognize the 3-sphere. In Pro-
ceedings of the International Congress of Mathematicians, vol-
ume 1, 2, pages pp. 601–611, Basel, 1995. Birkhäuser.

By a theorem of S.P. Novikov,
the problem is unsolvable if $n\geq 5$.
The idea is the following: By the Adjan--Rabin theorem,
there is a sequence of super-perfect groups $\pi_i$ for which the triviality problem is unsolvable. 
Now construct homology spheres $\Sigma_i$ with fundamental groups $\pi_i$.
If one can decide which of the $\Sigma_i$ are standard spheres,
then one can solve the triviality problem for the fundamental groups.

Question: Is the recognition problem for $S^4$ solvable?

The problem with this proof of S.P. Novikov's theorem is that there is no result that asserts that for any given super-perfect group $\pi$ there is a homology $4$-sphere satisfying $\pi_1(\Sigma) = \pi$.
However,
Kervaire has proved that every perfect group with the same amount of generators and relators may be realized as the fundamental group of a homology $4$-sphere.

Thus the question:
Is there an improved Adjan--Rabin theorem that asserts the existence of a sequence of perfect groups $\pi_i$ with the same amount of generators and relators,
the triviality problem of which is unsolvable?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As mentioned algorithmic 4-sphere recognition is an open problem.    Since Rubinstein's solution to the 3-sphere recognition problem is so simple and elegant, perhaps the first thing you might guess is, why not try those techniques in dimension 4?  Normal surfaces, crushing normal 3-spheres, searching for almost-normal 3-spheres.

That theory is still in its infancy.  Rubinstein and his former student Bell Foozwell have been developing normal co-dimension one manifold theory in triangulated manifolds.   They have a "normalization" process that follows Rubinstein's general normal/almost-normal schema but it appears to do a fair bit of damage to the manifolds, so it's not clear to me if anything like this could eventually be used for 4-sphere recognition, but maybe some creative variant of the idea will work-out.

Another closely-related problem would be an algorithmic Schoenflies theorem, to determine if a normal 3-sphere bounds a ball.

Answer (score 11):

A presentation with the same number of generators and relations is called *balanced*.  The triviality problem for balanced presentations (indeed, the word problem for balanced presentations) is a major unsolved problem.  Googling the phrase 'triviality problem for balanced presentations' will give lots of references.  Note that you may automatically assume that your groups $\pi_i$ are perfect, since the class of perfect groups is recursive.

Comment: Thank you for the answer,
I'll look into that. 
And thank you in particular for the remark on perfect groups!

Answer (score 11):

Recognition of $S^4$ is listed as an open problem in the survey of Shmuel Winberger "Homology Manifolds" (page 1088): http://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/~aar/homology/shmuel2.pdf with exactly the same reasoning that HW explained. Note that fundamental groups of homology 4-spheres need not be balanced (an example of Hausmann and Weinberger from 1984), still, nobody so far was able to exploit this.

Comment: The Hausmann--Weinberger example is good news. 
One might not have to solve the triviality problem for balanced groups then to get the S.P. Novikov theorem for $n=4$.

Comment: Do you know a reference for the Hausmann--Weinberger example? Or can you say more about it, eg what the fundamental group in question is? (I imagined the reference was http://math.uchicago.edu/~shmuel/HW.pdf but I believe that paper gives examples of non-balanced groups that are -not- fundamental groups of homology 4-spheres.)